# How to get a json bolean response from a php webservice to be captured in iOS app

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json

I am trying make an iOS App that checks to see (using) Email address if a user exists in the DB, of yes then it adds the user details along with the device token for push notifications in a mysql table, this whole part work fine. My issue is that I would like to get a response back from my php webservice file, if the user is not in my db, I just dont know how to implement a simple json response (in PHP) and how to capture it in the iOS APP. I am fairly new to programming so please detailed instruction would be most helpful.
my PHP code is as follows

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'root';
    $db = 'iOS';
    $dbtable = 'iosuser';
    $userT='user';



    // Connect Database
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die(mysql_error());


if (isset ($_GET["deviceID"]) && isset ($_GET["email"])){
    $deviceID = $_GET["deviceID"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];

} else {
  $deviceID ="fsfsfsdfsdfsdf";

}
//First confirm if user is already registered via website

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'",$conn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
// mysql_query($result,$conn) or die(mysql_error();

if ($num_rows > 0)
    {

//  $sql = "INSERT INTO $dbtable (id, deviceID) VALUES (NULL,'$deviceID');";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $dbtable (id, deviceID) SELECT user.id, '$deviceID' FROM user where email='$email';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }else {
    die("User Not Found");

}





// Insert value into DB
//$sql = "INSERT INTO $dbtable (id, deviceID) VALUES (NULL,'$deviceID');";
//$res = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($conn);

if($res) {          
$response = array('status' => '1');                 
} else {
die("Query failed");
}

echo json_encode($res);
exit();
?>
```

and in my iOS app this is the section i use to pass values to my DB

```
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.16.1.15/ios3.php?deviceID=%@&email=%@", _dtoken.text,_email.text];
   // NSLog(_email.text);

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the idea is that if my webservice php file say returns a boolean false (if the user is not in the DB) then my iOS app should capture that and take action accordingly (which ever that may be).
Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help
Hamood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are setting `status` to `'1'`, this that is a string value and then when you parse your code. Generally you'd return a string value.

   I would suggest that you either want to return a numeric value or a boolean value. If returning a boolean, you would do:

   ```
   $result = array('status' => true);
   ```

   Then, when you parse the JSON with `NSJSONSerialization`, you'll get a boolean `NSNumber`.

   Alternatively, you could return it as a numeric value:

   ```
   $result = array('status' => 1);
   ```

   This, when you parse it in Objective-C, will be an integer value `NSNumber`.

   Bottom line, using a string return code is atypical. You'd either return a numeric value or you'd return `true` or `false` (without quotes).
2. If you're going to use a single numeric code field, common convention is to return `0` for success and then any of a number of non-zero values for failure (the thinking being that you succeed in only one way, but you could fail for any of a number of reasons). Personally, I try to eliminate any ambiguity by having two fields, one is a boolean `success` field, and the other is a numeric `errorCode` field so that if `success` is `false`, the app could look at the `errorCode` to then determine why it failed, and then act accordingly. I might even include an `errorMessage` field, too, which describes the error in English (e.g. if MySQL error, report the actual MySQL error message).

   Implicit in this is that your technique of calling `die` is generally discouraged. That's harder for your app to parse and diagnose the source of the problem. Return valid JSON that indicates the nature of the error.

A couple of things unrelated to your immediate question:

1. I would discourage you from using the `mysql_` functions. That is now deprecated, so you'd generally use `mysqli_` function, or `PDO::` functions.
2. You should never take inputs provided in a request and then supply them to your MySQL queries. For example, if passing a parameter to a SQL and if you were using `mysqli_`, then you'd call `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape it before using it in SQL. Or you'd use `?` placeholders in your SQL and then manually bind values. But never just take request parameters and build SQL statements from them. That can lead to both innocent errors or catastrophic SQL injection attacks.
3. You should not use `dataWithContentsOfURL`. Use `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest` instead. You can google "sendAsynchronousRequest example" and you'll probably get tons of hits. But don't do synchronous requests.

Comment: Thank You Rob for suggestion and solution. I am still confused about the usage,return bolean value false if the User does not exist in the DB, take my php code:               if ($num_rows > 0)
    {


ID) SELECT user.id, '$deviceID' FROM user where email='$email';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }else {
    //This is where I want to return the bolean false;
    $response = array('status' => false);
    echo json_encode($response);
    die("User Not Found");

} .... Would this be the way to do it, and what would be the exact line in iOS APP to capture this?

Comment: Don't call `die` in your PHP code. Just return JSON with appropriate status codes. To parse the response use `NSJSONSerialization` (Google "NSJSONSerialization example" to see examples of how to use that).

Comment: I am trying this code which does not work  PHP:     else {
 //This where I want to return the json bolean value
 $response = array('status' => false); 
 echo json_encode($response);                               Xcode:  // Json capture attempt
    _json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    _responseArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   _r=[[_json objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(_r);

Comment: your JSON a is a dictionary, thus `NSError *parseError; NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:&parseError]; if (!responseDictionary) { NSLog(@"parseError=%@", parseError); } NSNumber *status = responseDictionary[@"status"];` Assuming everything is OK (no error message, and `status` is non-`nil`, etc.), you can now look at `[status boolValue]`.

Comment: Rob, implementing your suggested code crashes the application, nslog shows : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: So that suggests that there was no data. You now need to figure out why. If you used `sendAsynchronousRequest`, it would provide an error object which you could use to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Rob, Thank you so much for your help, your code does work, I had to change my php side code to :                                         $response ['status']= 1; 
echo json_encode($response);